# Delete A Record From A Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to delete a record: remove a routine,that belongs to a user, on button click (hasMany). I have set up the view, models and relationship within,delete route, and the controller method to delete.

When I try to click the button to remove the routine from the db, it does nothing. why does it not removing the record?

Here's my code: route:

 `Route::post('routine/delete', 'RoutineController@delete'); // Delete a routine for a user.`

Controller:

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{
        $id = $request->input("id"); // Getting the id via. the ajax request.

        $routine = \App\Routine::find($id); //Fetching the routine object from the db ifentified by the id passed via ajax

        if ($routine)
        {
            $routine->delete();
        }

        return ["status" => "success"];
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
       <!-- When this button is clicked, we determine which routine to remove. -->
            <button class="btn btn-danger remove_routine" data-id="{{$routine->id}}" data-token="{{csrf_token()}}" style="display:inline">Delete</button>
        </div>
```

User Model:

```
  public function routine()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Routine');
  }
```

Routine model:

```
 public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you get the correct id by ajax calling which you want to delete?

Comment: Where is the ajax portion of this problem? Are there any errors returned from the request in the browser console? If there was an error, you will be able to see the laravel stack trace in the network section of the dev tools.

Comment: I think I miss the ajax part here, since I don't have one for it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it exactly answers your question, and I don't use AJAX, but I always do my deletes like this:

**View**

```
@foreach($database-thing as $item)
    <form method="POST" action="$yourActionHere" style="display:inline" >
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
    </form>
@endforeach

// Even easier with laravelcollective/forms
@foreach($database-thing as $item)
    {!! Form::open([
        'method'=>'DELETE',
        'url' => [$yourUrl, $item->id // <-- Very important],
        'style' => 'display:inline'
    ]) !!}
    {!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Verwijder', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    YourModel::destroy($id);
    // All your other logic like redirects and stuff
}
```

Comment: I am now getting this error:
`Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\RoutineController::delete()`
You sure I don't need ajax for that?
what's the second argument from the url the `action` expects?

Comment: I have never done it with AJAX and it works just fine. The action probably is a URL or route you've set up. I work with RESTful controllers, so all my routes are resource routes.

Answer (score 0):

Working delete, based on the code above and this updated controller function:

```
 public function delete(Request $request,$id)
    {

        $user=Auth::user();
        $routine = \App\Routine::findOrFail($id); // find or throw an error if you don't find the routine id in db.
        // Makes if() statement redundant, since it checkes for that id already.

        // Need to check that the owner of the routine is the current authenticated user.
        if ($user->id != $routine->user->id)
        {
          Session::flash('flash_message', 'No routine found.');
        }
        else
        {
          $routine->delete();
          Session::flash('routine_deleted','Routine deleted!');
        }

        // No need to return $routine since I am deleting it, otherwise it will throw and error of trying to get property of non-object.

        return redirect()->back()->with('user') ;
        //return view('view_routine')->with('user', 'routine');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
$remove = 2;

$filtered = $c->filter(function ($value, $key) use($remove){
    return $value['id']!=$remove;
});
```